# Facebook Login Javascript SDK autologin if a cookie is set

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am Trying to set up my website so that when you go onto the login page it checks if a cookie is set and if it is then the login should be automatic - i.e. when this page loads it redirects to "Facebook.ashx" which creates a cookie to remember access token.

However if the cookie is not set then the user has to click on the Login with Facebook button to continue login which then continues to redirect to "Facebook.ashx" as before.

This is my code - at the moment it always logs in once the user has accepted the app and continues to "Facebook.ashx"

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'My_App_ID', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                // TODO: Handle the access token
                // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                var redirect = "FacebookLogin.ashx?redirect=" + document.getElementById('redirect').innerHTML;
                form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                form.setAttribute("action", redirect);

                var field = document.createElement("input");
                field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                form.appendChild(field);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });
    };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email, publish_stream">Login with Facebook</div>
```

Thanks For any help in advance

Comment: `auth.authResponseChange` will fire on each page load as long as the user is signed in - you probably want to subscribe to the login event instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out - simple fix

If you change the status to false rather than true then it waits for the user to click login and to check if cookie exists just a simple if statement to change the status to true or false like so:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("fb_token") > 0) //user has already logged in with facebook - process should be automatic
        var fb_status = true;
    else
        var fb_status = false;
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'My App ID', // App ID
            status: fb_status, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`auth.authResponseChange` will fire on each page load as long as the user is signed in.

What you want to do is to pass the 'known state' from the server to the client and then compare this inside `FB.getLoginStatus`. If the state has changes (such as the userID), then this constitutes a real login and you redirect to the ashx page to set new cookies.

As a quick example:

- Step one - load page, flush empty state (userID = 0)
- Step two - execute FB.getLoginStatus, compare authResponse.userID to userID
- Step three - since authResponse.userID <> 0, redirect to the page setting the cookies
- Step four - load page, flush state (userID = userID from authResponse.userID)
- Step five - execute FB.getLoginStatus, compare authResponse.userID to userID, since they match do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the response but my main problem is I want it to wait for the user to click the login with facebook button before it continues, however for some reason it is not waiting for the user to click
I have tried changing the code to this
FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
//rest of code as before

but it is still continuing automatically. How can i get it to wait for a response?
Thanks

Comment: The auth events will always fire automatically when you have `status: true` since a FB will try to resolve the status in the background.

Remove it and all will be good.